# Programmatically change Bit-bucket plugin settings

Tags: ansible, jira, bitbucket-server

I would like to change the settings for a bit-bucket plugin (Specifically look-and-feel) with Ansible. I asked this question in the Atlassian forum with no results. Since the Atlassian tools probably store their config information similarly, information about the other tools in the suite like Jira may be helpful.

Is there a REST API I could use?  A config file I can modify?  Database row I can change?

I suspect the information I need to change is stored in the database and I am going to start exploring in that direction.

Comment: The latest REST API (currently 7.6.0) doesn't seem to provide much server configuration options: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/latest/bitbucket-rest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a table in the database called plugin_settings. It's contains key-value config settings. 
For the look and feel plugin there were 4 rows. The schema and my data looks like this-

```
namespace                   key_name                        key_value                           id
bitbucket.global.settings   look-and-feel:HEADER_IMAGE      <64 bit encoded image>              74
bitbucket.global.settings   look-and-feel:MODIFIED_TIME     <Looks like an epoch time>          70
bitbucket.global.settings   look-and-feel:COLOR_MAP         #java.util.Map                      73
                                                            customThemePrimaryColour#403294     75
                                                            customThemeHeaderColour#403294
bitbucket.global.settings   look-and-feel:FAVICON_IMAGE     <64 bit encoded image>
```

I haven't determined yet if the REST API will allow me to modify these values but at the very least I 
will be able to modify the rows in the table.

If your use case is similar to mine, it looks like the easiest thing to do is install and configure BB
 somewhere temporarily then pull the values out of the table and put them in your ansible config; 
 especially for the 64 bit encoded images.

Comment: How can you update a `key_value` that is a java.util.Map?